# Why isn't my function recognized in the REPL

Tags: python, python-3.x, read-eval-print-loop

For some reason when I run my program in the REPL my module isn't recognized. I type in **from import words (fetch_words, print_words)** and receive the error *fetch_words is not defined*. This happens as as well when I type **import words**

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

def fetch_words():
    story = urlopen('https://sixty-north.com/c/t.txt')
    story_words = []
    for line in story:
        line_words = line.decode('utf-8').split()
        for word in line_words:
            story_words.append(word)
    story.close()
    return story_words



def print_words(story_words):
    for word in story_words:
        print(word)


def main():
    words = fetch_words
    print_words(words)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Could you put the contents of the other file too? And also the respective file names?

Comment: Can you provide the whole traceback?

Comment: This is my only file.Its labeled practice.py I access the prompt with user/desktop/file. Then I type python and import words leading me to this error. @AstikGabani Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'words'

Comment: @c_reyes What exactly did you type to import?

Comment: from urllib.request import urlopen

Comment: @c_reyes I mean in the prompt. How did you import `fetch_words` ?

Comment: from words import (fetch_words, print_words)

Comment: `from import words ...` is invalid. Seems like a typo of `from words import ...`.

Comment: @c_reyes What made you think the module was called `words`? The file is `practice.py`, so as a module it's called `practice`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrect syntax while importing the function.

Since you have named your file as `practice.py`, the correct syntax of importing the function defined within it will be :

```
from practice import fetch_words
```

Or in case you need to import multiple functions:

```
from practice import fetch_words, print_words
```

Remember, the name of the module to import from should be the same as the name of the file, without `.py` extension. In this case, the module is `practice`, and not `words`.

Comment: The syntax is fine actually, it's the name that's wrong.

Comment: @wjandrea his syntax seemed wrong to me on the first look. Maybe he had a typo there.

Comment: @bikalpa Oh, you're right, `from import words ...` is invalid. That would cause a different error though, so I think it was a typo while writing the question.

Comment: @c_reyes If it solved your problem, please kindly accept the answer so other programmers facing the same issue may solve their problem.